# TypeScript infer return type of a function that accepts function as an argument

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I want to infer return type of a function that accepts function as an argument. It's hard to explain it without the code. So here we go:

```
const funcNumber = (arg: boolean) => (code: string) => Promise.resolve(100)
const funcString = (arg: boolean) => (code: string) => Promise.resolve("Hello")

const doSomethingCool = (callback) => (code: string) => {
    const requestMethod = callback(false)

    return Promise.all([requestMethod(code)])
}

const inferNumberType = doSomethingCool(funcNumber) // Promise<any[]> should be Promise<number[]>
const inferStringType = doSomethingCool(funcString) // Promise<any[]> should be Promise<string[]>
```

I want `inferNumberType`  to have a type `Promise<number[]>` and `inferStringType`  to have a type `Promise<string[]>`.

Not really sure how to achieve it and  where to look for a solution since I know very little about TS.

Here is a playground: [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMAcggtgIwKYCcYC8MAFAIa4DmAXDJiCADbalgCUhAfCaACbY3RcASzAV2BLgAVcIdEIjYAdLmwRGAN2zEAjAAZdrAFChIsRMgDKUYaMIly1WvSYtxXYr34xBIsZxjSsvJKKmoMmsQARAAS2AwMIJFGxuDQMDwgFrLYUAAWvgDCznYepPGYpMAA1m7cIHwC1r61AN6GMB0wJmkqAI4IqlAAsjm59XbAZQwV1cRwZQrJnTAqUAi4YAEycgqKU8QA2n0D0CN59R712KwAukYAvoYppjAicHhoWHgAKgCeAA7YOwZLLoUaFZxzJCoDA4XDsAD0CK2QQUAB4WL8DjcuBAxggGDxaEDAjtsGiwLC8NiOM80m88FYbBQ-oDgZlsnkIYwoZYmqJEcjScEMWAsTjvPjCcSUWS0T5RDTDEA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a generic type parameter and use it to correctly type the `callback` parameter, it all works as expected

```
const funcNumber = (arg: boolean) => (code: string) => Promise.resolve(100)
const funcString = (arg: boolean) => (code: string) => Promise.resolve("Hello")

const doSomethingCool = <R>(callback: (a:boolean) => (code: string)=> Promise<R>) => (code: string) => {
    const requestMethod = callback(false)

    return Promise.all([requestMethod(code)])
}

const inferNumberType = doSomethingCool(funcNumber)('') // Promise<number[]>
const inferStringType = doSomethingCool(funcString)('') //  Promise<string[]>
```

[play](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMAcggtgIwKYCcYC8MAFAIa4DmAXDJiCADbalgCUhAfCaACbY3RcASzAV2BLgAVcIdEIjYAdLmwRGAN2zEAjAAZdrAFChIsRMgDKUYaMIly1WvSYtxXYr34xBIsZxjSsvJKKmoMmsQARAAS2AwMIJFGxuDQMDwgFrLYUAAWvgDCznYAPABKHB6k8ZikwADWNGRUdIzMbP4eIHwC1r6sEgEycgrlHG7c3V4+ohMA3oYwSzAmaSoAjgiqUACyObnddsDVDLUNxHDVCsnLMCpQCLhgQ0EKiifEANobW9B7ed0unxWABdIwAX0MKVMMBEcDwaCweAAKgBPAAO2DsGSy6H2hWcFyQqAwOFwrGIAHJKewAPS0l4jbAlFioz4grgQA4IBg8WhYwJMkpgUl4dkcaFpOF4Kw2ChozHYzLZPIExhEyx9WZUmkwemM4IssBsjnebm8-kG0YzCjiwxAA)

Comment: Thank you so much! That exactly what I was looking for :)